# google container startup script

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created /usr/startup.sh script in google container which would like to execute it on startup of every pod.

I tried it doing it through command in yaml like below.

command: "sh /usr/start.sh"
command: ["sh", "-c", "/usr/start.sh"]

Please let me if there is any kind of way that can execute defined script at the startup in google container/pod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at the postStart [lifecycle hook](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/container-environment/#hook-handler-execution).

An example can be found in the [kubernetes repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/examples/javaweb-tomcat-sidecar/javaweb-2.yaml):

```
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: resouer/myapp:v6
    lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command:
            - "cp"
            - "/app/myapp.war /work"
```

Here are the [API docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/api/types.go):

```
// Lifecycle describes actions that the management system should take in response to container lifecycle
// events.  For the PostStart and PreStop lifecycle handlers, management of the container blocks
// until the action is complete, unless the container process fails, in which case the handler is aborted.
type Lifecycle struct {
    // PostStart is called immediately after a container is created.  If the handler fails, the container
    // is terminated and restarted.
    PostStart *Handler `json:"postStart,omitempty"`
    // PreStop is called immediately before a container is terminated.  The reason for termination is
    // passed to the handler.  Regardless of the outcome of the handler, the container is eventually terminated.
    PreStop *Handler `json:"preStop,omitempty"`
}
```

Comment: Looks like its not working for ReplicationController. It works with the pod. Pod is going in "RunContainerError" status.
Please let me know if i am missing something 
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
namespace: default
name: testtomcat
spec:
replicas: 2
selector:
app: testtomcat
template:
metadata:
labels:
app: testtomcat
spec:
containers:
- name: testtomcat
image: gcr.io/project/tomcat-:v4
lifecycle:
postStart:
exec:
command:
- "/usr/start.sh"
ports:
- containerPort: 8080

Comment: Tried it like follow and its working fine now.

          lifecycle:
            postStart:
             exec:
                command:
                  - "sh"
                  - "/usr/local/s3fsmount.sh"

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Startup scripts run on node startup, not for every pod.  We don't currently have a "hook" in kubelet to run whenever a pod starts on a node.  Can you maybe explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: Using kind : ReplicationController in yaml
I am trying to mount google storage in Pod. Installed required packages on Docker Image and tested it on Google Container Engine. Manually mounting is working fine but unable to automate it. Tried using shell script with command parameter in the yaml file. Tried adding "my-bucket /mount/point gcsfuse rw,auto,user" in /etc/fstab but its not working. need to execute "mount /mount/point" command every time in the pod. I would like to execute "gcsfuse --implicit-dirs my-bucket /mount/point" or "mount /mount/point command at the startup of the pod.

Comment: Tried it like follow and its working fine now.

          lifecycle:
            postStart:
             exec:
                command:
                  - "sh"
                  - "/usr/local/s3fsmount.sh"

Thanks for help!